# append new msgpack data to end of file

Tags: msgpack

Is it valid to append objects to msgpack data without decoding it first?

I.e something like that:

- encode data1
- pack data1
- write packed data1 to file

Then,

- pack data2
- append packed data2 to end of file

or should it be:

- read file
- msgunpack file -> data1
- create data1_2 (including data1,data2)
- pack data1_2
- write packed data1_2 to file

Comment: I have the same question, but for python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just append to the file. Look at [How to unpack a msgpack file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969518/how-to-unpack-a-msgpack-file/32007631#32007631) for my sample code for reading an writing, you will see that I am appending as well, and this works.

Comment: So if you have an array encoded in msgpack, you can extend it just by adding the new msgpack data to the end of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Alex's answer, since the [spec](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md) still doesn't elucidate this, and I wasn't sure how to translate that paradigm to other libraries. I'm not sure if this is part of the official spec, but it's the least surprising way to implement, and it makes intuitive sense. It's extremely useful if you want an append-only data format.

You ought to be able to simply concatenate any packed msgpack objects. Your library should provide some kind of `Unpacker` class, which takes a byte stream comprising one or more concatenated msgpack objects, and emits a stream of unpacked structures. If your library lacks this feature, you probably have to implement it yourself.

Here's what that looks like in python's [msgpack](https://msgpack-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) package:

```
from io import BytesIO
import msgpack as mp

buf = BytesIO()
buf.write(packer.pack(1))
buf.write(packer.pack(2))
buf.write(packer.pack('foo'))
buf.write(packer.pack(True))
buf.write(packer.pack({"spam":"eggs"}))

print('file contents: {}'.format(buf.getvalue()))
buf.seek(0)

unpacker = mp.Unpacker(buf)
for i, obj in enumerate(unpacker):
    print('{}: {} {}'.format(i, repr(obj), type(obj)))
```

Out:

```
file contents: b'\x01\x02\xa3foo\xc3\x81\xa4spam\xa4eggs'
0: 1 <class 'int'>
1: 2 <class 'int'>
2: 'foo' <class 'str'>
3: True <class 'bool'>
4: {'spam': 'eggs'} <class 'dict'>
```

If you wish to implement your own, the python fallback [Unpacker](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python/blob/main/msgpack/fallback.py) is quite readable.